# Domain and codomain of pushforward and pullback

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle, pullback, pushforward

Let$F:M \to N$ be a smooth map of manifolds. The pointwise pushforward is a *linear* map
$$
F_{*,p} : T_p M \to T_{F(p)} N; \qquad v \mapsto F_{*,p}v: C^\infty(N) \ni \phi \mapsto v (\phi \circ F) \in \mathbb R
$$
and the pullback is its dual map
$$
F^*_p: T_{F(p)}^*N \to T_p^* M; \qquad f \mapsto f \circ F_{*,p}
$$

The question is: when one extends these maps to fields (even general tensor fields) on the whole manifold, then what should domain and the codomain of these maps be ? e.g. for the pushforward is it
$$
F_*: TM \to TN; \qquad \text{or}  \qquad F_*:\Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TN) \quad?
$$
in the first case it is a map of smooth manifolds, in the other it is an $\mathbb R$-linear map of vector spacees (or even a module homomorphism, right ?). Similarly for the pullback.

Comment: Unless $F$ is a diffeomorphism (or at least some injectivity is assumed) you cannot build the whole pushforward. Suppose $y=F(p)=F(q)$ for $p\neq q \in M$, and $X$ is a vector field in $M$. What should be the value at $y$ of $F_*X$? Should it be $F_{*p} X_p$ or should it be $F_{*q}X_q$? This is the basic problem.

However, the pullback does not present this kind of problems. In order to make all of this fit into your picture you should look at vector bundles in general. I'll let someone else write a better answer than what I can give.

Comment: I know about the problem you pointed out, I just forgot about it somehow because for me it is more important in case it worked (for the pullback at least, as map between sections) whether the pullback of sections can be considered a module homomorphism, while I think it is already a vector space homomorphism

Comment: The pullback can be viewed as a map between global sections. The pushforward can as well, but we need to view $F_*:\Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(F^*TN)$. (This is the "correct" viewpoint even fibrewise: The pushforward takes values in the pullback bundle $F^*TN$, not in $TN$ itself.)